# Stream de áudio (WebRadio)

Tags: node.js, socket.io, stream

Boa tarde.

Desculpem minha ignorância, mas como faço para criar uma web rádio (de forma bem rústica, apenas para fins de estudo)?

Meu projeto é o seguinte: tenho um site que reproduz o áudio e quem acessa o site ouve esse áudio.

Tenho que usar nodeJS, Socket.io, o que devo usar?

Quero entender como funciona essa lógica de stream.

Desde já mto obg.

Comment: se quer somente fazer um site tocar música, um plugin no site já faz isso, ou você levantar um servidor de música tipo o icecast? http://www.icecast.org/download/

Comment: Como seria "levantar um servidor de música" ?

Comment: Pedro este tutorial me ajudou neste problema, https://stmllr.net/blog/streaming-audio-with-mpd-and-icecast2-on-raspberry-pi/. A solução **IceCast** é bem completa, você configura um serviço que será disponibilizado em uma porta baseado na playlist. Esta playlist você cria com base um diretório com seus arquivos de música! Abraços

Comment: No site Subvisual Tutorial: HTML Audio Capture streaming to Node.js (no browser extensions)
by Gabriel Poca https://subvisual.co/blog/posts/39-tutorial-html-audio-capture-streaming-to-node-js-no-browser-extensions